# Ada GNATStudio gdb Breakpoints are not stopping in the debugger

Tags: debugging, gdb, breakpoints, ada, gnat

I'm new to Ada, and I created a sample program.

```ada
with Text_IO; use Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   Index : Integer;
  
begin

   Index := 123;
   -- Integer'Image means Int to str 
   Put_Line (Integer'Image (Index));
   New_Line; 

end Main;
```

When I put a breakpoint in Main,  on the line Put_Line, the program continues on as if I never set it.

Here's what I do to debug it.  Please correct me if I'm doing something wrong.

1. Set breakpoint on line 12.
2. Debugger Menu Item -> Initialize -> main
3. Debugger -> Start
4. Run Arguments:  (nothing)
   Unchecked "Stop at the beginning of main  subprogram"
   Unchecked "Use exec dir instead of current dir"

[image]

EDIT:

I solved this myself, I had to do a clean and build all, THEN go into Debugger Menu Item -> Initialize -> main

That gives me the little green line to start the debugger!

Comment: Did you check for debugger information in Builder section of the project ?

Comment: I set gdb as the debugger.  Not sure what else I should be looking for.  I added a screenshot of my settings

Answer (score 1):

I solved this myself, I had to do a clean and build all, THEN go into Debugger Menu Item -> Initialize -> main

That gives me the little green line to start the debugger!

1. Perform a 'Clean All' and make sure '-g' is used in the build path when you perform a 'Build All'.
2. Debugger Menu Item -> Initialize -> main
   Debugger -> Start
3. Run Arguments: (nothing) Unchecked "Stop at the beginning of main subprogram" Unchecked "Use exec dir instead of current dir"